# Thread call library function with parameter

Tags: c++, windows, mingw

I am trying to use the following function of my library in a thread:

```
typedef void (*TIPO_FUNCION_APARCAR_COMMIT)       (HCoche hc);
typedef void (*TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE)       (HCoche hc);
typedef void (*TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE_COMMIT)(HCoche hc);
int PARKING2_aparcar(HCoche,void *datos,TIPO_FUNCION_APARCAR_COMMIT,
                                             TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE,
                                             TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE_COMMIT);
```

But I can't figure out how I can call it, because in `CreateThread()` the input parameter is `LPVOID` and I don't see how I can use it.

I tried this syntax, but it doesn't work:

```
CreateThread(0, 0, fPARKING2_apagar, {&hc,(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)fPARKING2_getDatos(hc), &commit, &goForward, &goForwardCommit}, NULL, NULL, &threadId);
```

I also tried to use `std::thread`, but it seems that I don't have C++11 so I can't use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `fPARKING2_apagar()` function you are trying to pass to `CreateThread()` does not satisfy the signature that `CreateThread()` is expecting. The signature of your thread function MUST match that of [`ThreadProc()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686736.aspx):

```
DWORD WINAPI ThreadProc(_In_ LPVOID lpParameter);
```

Also, you are trying to pass an anonymous struct to the `lpParameter` param of `CreateThread()`.  That will not work, either.

You need to write a wrapper function that you can pass to `CreateThread()`, and then that wrapper can call the library function.  Use the `lpParameter` param of `CreateThread()` to pass user-defined data to the thread function, which can then pass it on to the library function as needed.

Try something more like this:

```
struct PARKING2_aparcar_params
{
    HCoche hc;
    void *datos;
    TIPO_FUNCION_APARCAR_COMMIT aparcarCommit;
    TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE permisoAvance;
    TIPO_FUNCION_PERMISO_AVANCE_COMMIT permisoAvanceCommit;
};

DWORD WINAPI PARKING2_aparcar_wrapper(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    PARKING2_aparcar_params *params = static_cast<PARKING2_aparcar_params*>(lpParameter);
    fPARKING2_aparcar(params->hc, params->datos, params->aparcarCommit, params->permisoAvance, params->permisoAvanceCommit);
    delete params;
    return 0;
}

...

PARKING2_aparcar_params *params = new PARKING2_aparcar_params;
params->hc = hc;
params->datos = fPARKING2_getDatos(hc);
params->aparcarCommit = &commit;
params->permisoAvance = &goForward;
params->permisoAvanceCommit = &goForwardCommit;

hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, &PARKING2_aparcar_wrapper, params, 0, &threadId);
if (!hThread)
    delete params;
```